# WSO2 VFS FTP Proxy create dynamically

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

At the moment, I am creating VFS Proxy services in WSO2 manually.
But I need to create services like this based on user input. There is no problem in generating a required XML. But I yet to find a way to dynamically import those XML into WSO2.

Does anyone know a way to make this work without manual service creation?

An example service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="FileProxy" startOnLoad="true" statistics="disable" trace="disable" transports="vfs">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <log level="full"/>
            <clone>
                <target sequence="fileWriteSequence"/>
            </clone>
        </inSequence>
    </target>
    <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">15</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file:///in</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">file:///out/out</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.txt</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">file:///out/out</parameter>
    <description/>
</proxy>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to achive this.

1.) Use the admin services to create a proxy, that´s what we are doing for a couple of years now without problems

https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI630/Working+with+Admin+Services

2.) Just generate a XML file (like above) in the directory ESB_HOME/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/proxy-services

Regards
Martin